# Grouping By different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have returned rows which look like this:

```
2 - Eggs
3 - Bacon
4 - Bacon Smoked
```

I would like to group by '%Bacon%' so that my count is `2`.

How can i do this is SQL?

I should see results like this:

`Eggs - 1
Bacon - 2`

Comment: Use a case statement to build your derived breakfast foods column.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following ([**Demo**](http://rextester.com/GEJ72828)):

```
SELECT 'Eggs' AS Category, COUNT(*) AS MyCount
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyField LIKE '%Eggs%'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Bacon' AS Category, COUNT(*) AS MyCount
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyField LIKE '%Bacon%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solution:

```
 SELECT 
    Eggs = SUM(CASE WHEN FoodColumn LIKE '%Eggs%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
    Bacon = SUM(CASE WHEN FoodColumn LIKE '%Bacon%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
 FROM Test
```

You can see demo [here](http://rextester.com/NHFDJ68149).

If you need to *separate the result into two separate rows*

```
 SELECT *
 FROM
 (
    SELECT 
       Eggs = SUM(CASE WHEN FoodColumn LIKE '%Eggs%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),
       Bacon = SUM(CASE WHEN FoodColumn LIKE '%Bacon%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM Test 
 ) AS Test
 UNPIVOT
 (
    Quantity FOR Foods IN (Eggs, Bacon)
 ) AS Result
```

You can see demo [here](http://rextester.com/DPWUL64730).

Comment: This would not separate the result into two separate rows like **@PriceCheaperton** was asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but I think it should work

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as QTY, RS.FOOD_TYPE
FROM 
(SELECT 
Case patIndex ('%[ /-]%', LTrim (FOOD_TYPE))
        When 0 Then LTrim (FOOD_TYPE)
        Else substring (LTrim (FOOD_TYPE), 1, patIndex ('%[ /-]%', LTrim (FOOD_TYPE)) - 1)
End FOOD_TYPE
FROM YOUR_TABLE) RS
GROUP BY RS.FOOD_TYPE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create table MyTable
(id int, FieldName varchar(50) )

insert into MyTable values (1, 'Eggs')
insert into MyTable values (2, 'Bacon')
insert into MyTable values (3, 'Bacon Smoked')



select count(FieldName), FieldName from (
select 
    case
        when charindex('eggs', FieldName) > 0 then 'eggs'
        when charindex('bacon', FieldName) > 0 then 'bacon'
    end as FieldName
from MyTable) as myMyTablealias
group by FieldName
```

[check it out](http://rextester.com/IBIC82926)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very specific case.. can you provide more Data? Does this help in anyway?

```
with list (item) as (
    select  
    item
    from (
        values 
            ('Eggs'),
            ('Bacon'),
            ('Bacon Smoked')) list (item)
)
select
    LEFT(item,
        (case 
            when CHARINDEX(' ',item,1) = 0 
            then LEN(item) 
            else CHARINDEX(' ',item,1) end)
    ) filtered,
    COUNT(*)
from list
group by
    LEFT(item,
    (case 
        when CHARINDEX(' ',item,1) = 0 
        then LEN(item) 
        else CHARINDEX(' ',item,1) end))
```